# CSS Change td size

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a nice looking table. I found a template and I want to modify it. The problem is that if I want to modify the font size of the top headers, the ones inside "`head_nav`" like this : `#head_nav th{ font-size: 30px;}` nothing happens. Am I doing something wrong? Also I want to make the data "TD" a square size, not rectangle, so I tried this: `tr, td{ width: 100%; height:100%;}` but again nothing happens.

This is my code :

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Timetable</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    body
    {
        font-family: arial;
    }

    th,td
    {
        margin: 0;
        text-align: center;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        outline: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
    }

    td
    {
        padding: 5px 10px;
    }

    th
    {
        background: #666;
        color: white;
        padding: 5px 10px;
    }

    td:hover
    {
        cursor: pointer;
        background: #666;
        color: white;
    }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <table width="80%" align="center" >
    <div id="head_nav">
    <tr>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Monday</th>
        <th>Tuesday</th>
        <th>Wednesday</th>
        <th>Thrusday</th>
        <th>Friday</th>
        <th>Saturday</th>
    </tr>
    </div>  
    
        <tr>
            <th>10:00 - 11:00</th>
            
                <td>Physics-1</td>
                <td>English</td>
                <td title="No Class" class="Holiday"></td>
                <td>Chemestry-1</td>
                <td>Alzebra</td>
                <td>Physical</td>
            </div>
        </tr>
    
        <tr>
            <th>11:00 - 12:00</td>
            
                <td>Math-2</td>
                <td>Chemestry-2</td>
                <td>Physics-1</td>
                <td>Hindi</td>
                <td>English</td>
                <td>Soft Skill</td>
            </div>
        </tr>
    
        <tr>
            <th>12:00 - 01:00</td>
            
                <td>Hindi</td>
                <td>English</td>
                <td>Math-1</td>
                <td>Chemistry</td>
                <td>Physics</td>
                <td>Chem.Lab</td>
    
            </div>
        </tr>
    
        <tr>
            <th>01:00 - 02:00</td>
            
                <td>Cumm. Skill</td>
                <td>Sports</td>
                <td>English</td>
                <td>Computer Lab</td>
                <td>Header</td>
                <td>Header</td>
    
            </div>
        </tr>
    
        <tr>
            <th>02:00 - 03:00</td>
            
                <td>Header</td>
                <td>Header</td>
                <td>Header</td>
                <td>Header</td>
                <td>Header</td>
                <td>Header</td>
            </div>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: You might want to put your css in a different file

Comment: you should use `!important` but it is bad practice in case of table you can use it

Comment: Your HTML is not valid. You can’t put a `<div>` directly in a `<table>` and you have closing `</div>`s without opening tags.

Comment: You can't have a div in a table, so I presume the browser is compensating for the error in such a way that the th is no longer inside the div. See what happens if you give the id to the tr instead, then you can dispense with the div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is invalid, try this.

```
 table tr:first-of-type
```

Don't insert table elements in divs, either use specific selectors, or give classes/id's to your td/tr's.

As you've also been told, inline CSS is a bad practice, so move it in a separate CSS file.

```css
  body {
      font-family: arial;
  }
  th, td {
      margin: 0;
      text-align: center;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      outline: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
  }
  td {
      padding: 5px 10px;
  }
  th {
      background: #666;
      color: white;
      padding: 5px 10px;
  }
  td:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
      background: #666;
      color: white;
  }
  table tr:first-of-type {
      font-size:30px;
  }
```

```html
<title>Timetable</title>
<table width="80%" align="center">
    <tr>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Monday</th>
        <th>Tuesday</th>
        <th>Wednesday</th>
        <th>Thrusday</th>
        <th>Friday</th>
        <th>Saturday</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>10:00 - 11:00</th>
        <td>Physics-1</td>
        <td>English</td>
        <td title="No Class" class="Holiday"></td>
        <td>Chemestry-1</td>
        <td>Alzebra</td>
        <td>Physical</td>
        </div>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>11:00 - 12:00</td>
            <td>Math-2</td>
            <td>Chemestry-2</td>
            <td>Physics-1</td>
            <td>Hindi</td>
            <td>English</td>
            <td>Soft Skill</td>
            </div>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>12:00 - 01:00</td>
            <td>Hindi</td>
            <td>English</td>
            <td>Math-1</td>
            <td>Chemistry</td>
            <td>Physics</td>
            <td>Chem.Lab</td>
            </div>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>01:00 - 02:00</td>
            <td>Cumm. Skill</td>
            <td>Sports</td>
            <td>English</td>
            <td>Computer Lab</td>
            <td>Header</td>
            <td>Header</td>
            </div>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>02:00 - 03:00</td>
            <td>Header</td>
            <td>Header</td>
            <td>Header</td>
            <td>Header</td>
            <td>Header</td>
            <td>Header</td>
            </div>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What does th,td{ } do ?

Comment: It applies the style between the brackets to both `th` and `td` elements. [explanation](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_comma.asp)

Answer (score 0):

As the code you have done is invalid. check this one it might help you...

```css
 body {
   font-family: arial;
 }
 th,
 td {
   margin: 0;
   text-align: center;
   border-collapse: collapse;
   outline: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
 }
 td {
   padding: 5px 10px;
 }
 th {
   background: #666;
   color: white;
   padding: 5px 10px;
 }
 td:hover {
   cursor: pointer;
   background: #666;
   color: white;
 }
```

```html
<table width="80%" align="center">
  <tr>
    <th>Time</th>
    <th>Monday</th>
    <th>Tuesday</th>
    <th>Wednesday</th>
    <th>Thrusday</th>
    <th>Friday</th>
    <th>Saturday</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>10:00 - 11:00</th>

    <td>Physics-1</td>
    <td>English</td>
    <td title="No Class" class="Holiday"></td>
    <td>Chemestry-1</td>
    <td>Alzebra</td>
    <td>Physical</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>11:00 - 12:00</td>

      <td>Math-2</td>
      <td>Chemestry-2</td>
      <td>Physics-1</td>
      <td>Hindi</td>
      <td>English</td>
      <td>Soft Skill</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>12:00 - 01:00</td>

      <td>Hindi</td>
      <td>English</td>
      <td>Math-1</td>
      <td>Chemistry</td>
      <td>Physics</td>
      <td>Chem.Lab</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>01:00 - 02:00</td>

      <td>Cumm. Skill</td>
      <td>Sports</td>
      <td>English</td>
      <td>Computer Lab</td>
      <td>Header</td>
      <td>Header</td>

  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>02:00 - 03:00</td>

      <td>Header</td>
      <td>Header</td>
      <td>Header</td>
      <td>Header</td>
      <td>Header</td>
      <td>Header</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```